# Delete duplicate JSON file based on one of the attributes

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have two directories in my linux system, `/dir` and `/dir2`

Both have more than 4000 JSON files. The JSON content of every file is like

```
{
   "someattribute":"someValue",
   "url":[
      "https://www.someUrl.com/xyz"
   ],
   "someattribute":"someValue"
}
```

Note that url is an array, but it always contains one element (the url).

The url makes the file unique. If there is a file with the same url in `/dir` and `/dir2` then it's a duplicate and it needs to be deleted.

I want to automate this operation either using a shell command preferrably. Any opinion how I should go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to get a list of duplicates:

```sh
jq -nrj '[
  foreach inputs.url as [$url] ({};
    .[$url] += 1;
    if .[$url] > 1 then input_filename
    else empty end
  )
] | join("\u0000")' /{dir1,dir2}/*.json
```

And to remove them, pipe above command's output to xargs:

```
xargs -0 rm --
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty bash script that uses [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the URL from the json files, and awk to detect and delete duplicates:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

rm -f urls-dir1.txt urls-dir2.txt

for file in dir1/*.json; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$file" $(jq '.url[0]' "$file") >> urls-dir1.txt
done
for file in dir2/*.json; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$file" $(jq '.url[0]' "$file") >> urls-dir2.txt
done

awk -F $'\t' 'FNR == NR  { urls[$2] = 1; next }
              $2 in urls { system("rm -f \"" $1 "\"") }' urls-dir1.txt urls-dir2.txt

rm -f urls-dir1.txt urls-dir2.txt
```

It assumes that dir2 has the files that are to be deleted as duplicates and the ones in dir1 should be untouched.

Comment: You're slightly short on quoting -- would correctly handle cases where the jq output contains whitespace as `printf "%s\t%s\n" "$file" "$(jq '.url[0]' "$file")"` (modern command substitution syntax has its own quoting context). And consider putting the redirections on the same line as the `done`s; making it `for ...; done >urls-dir1.txt` not only ensures that you don't build up output across multiple invocations, it's also faster to run since it doesn't keep re-opening and re-closing the same file every time it wants to write a single line to it.

Comment: Alternately, you could avoid using temporary files altogether if using command substitution. `urlsDir1() { for file in dir1/*.json; do ...; done; }; urlsDir2() { ...; }; awk ... <(urlsDir1) <(urlsDir2)`

Comment: Your script is indeed quick and dirty. you are repeating the directory handling twice and could do it in the same loop. I think you also merge urls-dir*.txt into one file. And eventually eliminate use of utility files using pipes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Java approach to achieve this:

```
Set<String> urls = new HashSet<>();
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.list(Paths.get("/path/to/your/folder"))) {
    paths
            .map(path -> new FileInfo(path, extractUrl(path)))
            .filter(info -> info.getUrl() != null)
            .filter(info -> !urls.add(info.getUrl()))
            .forEach(info -> {
                try {
                    Files.delete(info.getPath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This uses the following `FileInfo` class:

```
public class FileInfo {
    private Path path;
    private String url;
    // constructor and getter
}
```

First of all it reads all files in the given directory and extracts the URL. It filters all duplicates with the help of the `HashSet`. At the end all files containing duplicate URLs are going to be deleted.

There are multiple options to extract the `url` from each file:

*Quick and dirty using a regex:*

```
private String extractUrl(Path path) {
    try {
        String content = String.join("\n", Files.readAllLines(path));
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"url\".+\\s+\"(?<url>[^\\s\"]+)\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group("url");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

A better solution would be using a JsonParser Library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
private String extractUrl(Path path) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyObject object = mapper.readValue(reader, MyObject.class);
        return object.getUrls().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This uses an Object representation of the file content:

```
public class MyObject {
    @JsonProperty("url")
    private List<String> urls;
    // getter and setter
}
```

But at the end, the most performant solution probably would be to use a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and simple awk script that does all the work from base dir.

The awk script named `script1.awk`

```
/https/{
    if ($1 in urlArr) {
        cmd = "rm " FILENAME;
        print cmd;
        //system(cmd);
    } else {
        urlArr[$1] = FILENAME;
    }
}
```

Initially run the script with the following command:

`awk -f script1.awk dir{1,}/*.json`

When ready to remove the duplicate json files, just uncomment the 5th line (line containing `system(cmd)`). And run again.

Here are some explanations:

1. The `awk` command runs the script `script1.awk` on all json files in sub directory dir and dir1.
2. The script traverse each file, extract the URL text having https into variable $1.

   If variable $1 already exist in associative array urlArr print/remove the file.

   Else add current file into associative array urlArr.

Hope you like this simple solution.